# Pin# automatically appears in my Credit Card page

Tags: asp.net, security

I have an ASP.NET WebForm application, in one of my webform I have a page where I am taking Credit Card information from my customers, suddenly what we saw that, a textbox auto appears asking for PIN# and underneath it says "5% Discount with Pin On Debit Transactions".

This is very strange situation and we have disabled that functionality, but still we unable to find what entity/service/javascript file or whatever is adding a textbox asking for pin# and adding a label says "5% Discount with Pin On Debit Transactions" in our credit card page.

I also attached a screen shot for better understanding:

[image: chrome screen shot]

Comment: Contact your payment processor

Comment: Check txtCCPin's visible property, somewhere in your code-behind, you are enabling the visibility. Alternatively, you could just delete the txtCCPin textbox from your ASPX page and that will help identify all the places that the control is used. Lastly, if the control needs to stay on the page, there is some logic somewhere in your codebehind that is enabling the visibility (unless you toggle the visibility via javascript and not txtCCPin.Visible = true/false

Comment: I already make it sure that, there is no txtCCPin control exists in my aspx page as well as not generating dynamically from my code-behind and absolutely not from javascripts.

2 more point that I just uncover are, it only happening in live application not on my development (localhost), secondly when I change the page name it fixed (Pin# textbox not appear).

Comment: Was the site hacked? I'm not that familiar with creditcard transactions but if you have the number and the pin you can use the card for yourself right? Or is it a UserControl from a payment processor? In that case follow the advise of @Martheen.

Comment: This is not the UserControl or any code piece provided by  payment processor, It seems that credit card page hacked, but how, this is the BIG QUESTION MARK here.

2 Big clues are, it only happening in live application not on my development (localhost), secondly when I change the page name it fixed (Pin# textbox not appear).

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Start with this: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server/218011#218011

Comment: We have deployed that application on godaddy, that application not deployed on dedicated server, the server and entire application is working fine, only the page where we are getting the credit card information the pin# textbox auto appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some external resource (host) a JavaScript file named "addonjs.js" been calls from our page, we have removed that reference and the problem fixed.